# Freshdesk: Automating 'score' emails

Tags: automation, email, freshdesk

Background: I have little coding experience (not API savvy) and would preferably use an automation tool for this but hope for some guidance in the best way to complete the task. '

We need to send a 'response' (number of emails sent by an agent) score at least twice a day to agents so they can gauge their efficiency. As an alternative we can build up a dashboard to enable easy viewing of this information.

Question: How do I go about sending emails to each agents gmail account with the number of responses completed on Freshdesk that day? Can this be done with a Zapier connection to googlesheets and then forming a googlescript? Would it be easier to set up a live dashboard displaying all agents scores and if so how would you recommend doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Sending emails would be tough given that most email clients (gmail, outlook, ...) have stricter rules on what lands in inbox to avoid spamming.

But you can build a dashboard in Freshdesk to show this information. The [sdk](https://developer.freshdesk.com/v2/docs/quick-start/) has default support for most things you'd need. 
Here's a blog post of a sample dashbaord app in Freshdesk: https://medium.com/freshworks-developer-blog/building-a-full-page-app-on-freshdesk-5ce17524277f